# Getting Faulting application error in application log

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, foxpro

We are using some legacy foxpro pages in our asp.net application, we are using an .exe to handle the foxpro page requests and also using WC.dll. It was working fine, but suddenly getting the following error

```
Faulting application danamateweb.exe, version 0.0.0.0, stamp 47139f24, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 5.2.3790.4455, stamp 49900d60, debug? 0, fault address 0x0002cac2.
```

I do not have any idea, how to resolve this issue, our production is down, and DEV and Test box have no problem

Answer (score 0):

WC.dll is a part of webconnect  (http://www.west-wind.com/).

I suggest restarting IIS or the server if that doesn't work.

Depending on how it is installed these might get you an error log:

/admin/wc.wc?wwmaint~showlog~Error

/admin/wc.wc?wwMaint~wcDLLErrorLog